# AVAudioEngine vs AudioToolbox audio units

Tags: core-audio, avaudioengine, audiotoolbox

I want to build a DAW for macos and I am wondering what would be the best approach. Using AudioToolbox and core audio functionalities or AVAudioEngine? I am bit confused because I've seen that AUgraph is deprecated so I was wondering if audio development for mac is moving towards AVAudioEngine.

Comment: I know I've always felt regret every time I've used `AVAudioEngine`. Yes, `AUGraph`s are deprecated, but they still work, and you can always replace them with `AudioUnit`s and `kAudioUnitProperty_MakeConnection`.

Comment: Thanks. I am completely new when it comes to audio programming for macos. Could I also ask, from your experience is there any benefit for programming in objective C compared to C++?

Comment: One advantage is that Objective-C is callable from with swift. For this reason I often find myself using Objective-C++

Comment: Gordon: Why do you feel regret for using AVAudioEngine? I am using it for an application I am developing, and so far it seems good. Any specific pitfalls?